# Pin the link of the Area 51 Proposal to this site

Tags: feature-request

[The link to the Area 51 Proposal is here.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456) This would be useful because you would be able to see how well the site is doing in beta without searching for the Area 51 Proposal. Of course, this would be removed when it comes out of beta.

Comment: I believe this is only done once we are in Public Beta